# I can't access specific value store flutter

Tags: flutter, firebase, dart, google-cloud-firestore

I had this problem where I couldn't access specific value and rather print everything out.
I finger why it does that and though I post about it maybe it help someone.

I couldn't access specific value.

```
@override
void initState() {
  /*get data*/
  getData();
  userId = FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser!.uid;
  super.initState();
}

getData() async {

  try {
    if (widget.listId != null) {
      var userSnap = await FirebaseFirestore.instance
          .collection('Lists')
          .doc(widget.listId)
          .get();

      setState(() {
        listData = userSnap.data()!;
        _isloaded = true;
      });
    }
  } catch (e) {
    print(e.toString());
  }
}

var userId;//the user visiting the page
var listData = {};
bool _isloaded  =false;
```

here where it went wrong:

```
 Text(
     "$listData['Title']",
  ),
```

The output:

```
{uid: 8qqfIvsJ5fbkdOEeyrqiunYCBw52, Description: , Cover: , ListID: c79697b0-296e-11ed-8a73-b9da6639ae48, Access: true, Title: K, Tags: []}['Title']
```

#### solution

I shouldn't but it in "" and just write it without like this:

```
 Text(
     listData['Title'],
 ),
```

The output:

```
K
```

Comment: You can undelete the answer or post the solution on answer section,

Comment: Please don't post your solution as part of the question, but instead post it as an answer below. That improves the chances that others will find it, and let's the system (and the others) know that your problem has been solved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please replace

```
Text(
  "$listData['Title']",
),
```

With

```
Text(
  "${listData['Title']}",
),
```

You can read about string interpolation [here](https://medium.com/run-dart/dart-dartlang-introduction-string-interpolation-8ed99174119a).